# How can i call one webservice from another webservice and return the result

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am new to writing rest services. I have written a webservice to query mysql db and return data as JSON.Using jersey 1.9, war file is hosted on tomcat 7 and MySql db.

There is an existing webservice written and maintained by third party where i need to post this data.

I would like to know if it is possible to call WebService-2  from WebService-1 and return the response of Webservice-2 through WebService-1.

I would like to note that Webservice-2 cannot be altered. It currently takes JSONObject by POST and returns another JSONObject as the response.

Comment: sure - try it and see

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are looking for this API Example:

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource("<some_address>/<resource>");

ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);
//modify the response
//return the value
```

You can do it through jersey API.